# how to loop through an array when setting the data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I would like to know how to have a dynamic data in JavaScript. Here's the code:

```
function createChart(selected) {
if (selected === "SMPC5") {
    var distanceChart = Highcharts.chart('smpc5Chart', {
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'SMPC5',
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                size: '5'
            }
        },
```

...

```
function afisChart(selected) {
var mychart = createChart(selected);
mychart.showLoading();
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: "/Statistics/GetChartData/",
    data: { data: selected },
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        while (mychart.series.length > 0) {
            mychart.series[0].remove(false);
        }
        var xAxisCategories;
        if (selected == "SMPC5") {
            for (var key in data) {
                if (key == "date") {
                    document.getElementById("updatedate").textcontent = "last updated: " + data[key];
                }
                else if (key == "Date") {
                    xAxisCategories = data[key];
                }
                else {
                    mychart.addSeries({ name: key, data: data[key] }, false);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (selected == "GVP4") {
```

....

The selected data is bind with the data that it's in C# Controller. What I want is to save the data in an array or list(from controller) and after that send it to JavaScript and loop through it(not test every time using the if and else condition)

Comment: I don´t unsertand your question. Maybe you can show your C#-code also, as it´s hard to guess what you exactly mean. Please elaborate on where you want to save that data and where you want to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't help at all, but I would refer you to the following javascript array functions to solve any problem like this. Once your data is in the array you can use one of them to filter or apply some change to each item and get the new values back individually or as a new array.

Click these to learn more about each.

[Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

[Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

[Array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

[Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=a)

If I knew more about what you were trying to do I could be more specific.

Comment: OK. Thanks.. what I want is to put the data into the array from controller(have a function in controller that returns the array and access the resulted array in JavaScript)..